# Excel number formatting thousands is not working

Tags: excel, format, numbers

With Excel, I am trying to format my numbers to display as thousands.
1000 should be 1 k.
I usually use the format numbers from Excel. Depending on the language, I add a "space" or a "," after the last digit of my formatting in order to get a x1000 division.

I used to have:
Format numbers in thousand: 0, "K" (US) or 0 space "K" (French, for instance)
Format numbers in millions: 0,,"M" (US) or 0 double-space "M" (French, for instance)

However, it is not working anymore and now it just displays my numbers with a comma/two commas at the end instead of having thousands or millions.

Do you know what it could be related to and how to parameter the cells format?

In my Advanced settings, I am using the "," as Decimal separator, and the " " as Thousands separator. I unchecked the regional parameters.

Here are the details of my settings:
***Advanced settings***
[image: Advanced settings]

Here is what is shown on several examples:
***Details of cases not working***
[image: Details of cases not working]

Note: I would like to avoid having a formula as I only want to act on the cells format. For now, my workaround (not satisfying) is creating a "mirror" page using =ROUND(Cell/1000000;0) to display Millions, for instance

Thank you for your help

Comment: The methods that "used to work" still work. Since you have chosen to not share what you are using, can't tell what you are doing incorrectly. Maybe your system thousands separators have changed.

Comment: Thank you.

Here are the details of what I am using:


25000000      when format is: Standard
25 000 000,00      when format is: # ##0,00
25 000 000  M€     when format is: # ##0  "M€" (there are 2 spaces before my quote marks)

I am using the "," as Decimal separator, and the " " as Thousands separator

Comment: Seems to work OK here **IF** my regional settings are set to **space** and **comma** (for both currency and number).  Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION to show exactly what you have in the custom Number Format box as well as your input and incorrect output. BTW, if I set up the formats with one set of decimal and digit separators, and then change to another set, the Number Format is maintained. No need to change them. I have the Advanced settings set to use System Separators.

Comment: Change it to what I wrote

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what I should be changing?

I have added the pictures of my Advanced settings + a screenshot of what is displayed in the "Number Format" box

Comment: The results are the same when I tick "Use system parameters"

Comment: And what are your Windows regional separators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number Format (Excel Advanced settings:  ***Use System Separators***

- If Region is set to French (France):

  ```
   <1000]# ##0 \€;[<1000000]# ##0  k\€;# ##0   \m\€
  ```
- If Region is set to English (United States)

  ```
   [<1000]#,##0 €;[<1000000]#,##0, k€;#,##0,, \m€
  ```

And if you change the region, and close and re-open the workbook, the settings will switch.

***Opened with Region = US english settings***
[image]

***Closed then Re-opened with Region = French France***
[image]

You may find it simpler to set the number format using the US region settings to avoid confusion between `<space>` as a **space** vs `<space>` as a **thousands separator**

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems the confusion is indeed related to the fact that the "space" is not perceived the same way as a space vs as a thousands separator.
Your number format worked anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

to do so, follow these steps:

1- choose cells you want to change format.

2- Press Ctrl+1 to open formatting popup (Number tab)

3- select 'Custom'

4- Enter this pattern for converting into thousands with K:
#,##0.0, "K"

5- And this pattern for converting into millions with M:
#,##0.0,,"M"

Comment: Thank you for youzr reply.

This is what I've tried, and this only adds the commas and the "K" or "M" at the end, instead of what I expect it to do.

When applying the pattern #,##0.0, "K", I get: 25,000,000.0,K
When applying the pattern #,##0.0,, "M", I get: 25,000,000.0,,M

Comment: it works on my Excel, version 2021